# lambda funtion that can return nothing

Tags: python, lambda

i want to write a lambda function in python and use it with map to create a list which contains even members of current list
for example I can do this without lambda:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
def f(x):
  if x % 2 == 0:
    return x
  else:
    return
print map(f,a)
```

Comment: This isn't something you can do purely with `map` and a `lambda`. Lambda expressions (and functions/methods in general) cannot return nothing, they return something or `None`. At best, therefore, you could get `[None, 2, None, 4]` - you need a `filter` step, or just use a list comprehension `[x for x in a if x % 2 == 0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `map(f,a)` call returns:

```
[None, 2, None, 4]
```

Here is corresponding `lambda` function to replace `f` in `map()` and return same result:

```
>>> map(lambda x:None if x%2 else x, a)
[None, 2, None, 4]
```

If you do not want `None` to be the part of list, use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) instead of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: not x%2, a)
[2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) works nicely here.

```
>>> print filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [1,2,3,4])
[2, 4]
```

You could also use a list comprehension. The important takeaway being that the functional concept of `map` is to apply a transformation to every element of an iterable type (*1 to 1 ratio*).

Where as filter does exactly what you require, either retaining or discarding elements based on a conditional expression. Please refer to usage [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).